# Shipping calculator Button at Checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to woocommerce and I do not have much knowledge about that. In a project I want to hide shipping calculation button from cart page.but want to show the same configuration with button on checkout page.

I want help regarding how to add shipping button on checkout.

Comment: Please, provide part of your code.

Comment: You'll need to alter your theme's Woocommerce checkout and cart templates, but as Viktor said, it's very hard to help you with the issue if you don't post any code.

Comment: Here is code for my cart page which contains calculate button

https://pastebin.com/wAs548gS

Here is code for checkout page shipping ,where I want cart's page button

https://pastebin.com/vXzhtz7D

Answer (score 1):

you can fire an event after calc_shipping buton is clicked, but you need to wait native calc_shipping method to end. I used jQuery(document).ajaxComplete to wait that execution:

```
jQuery('[name="calc_shipping"]').click(function () {
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    your_pretty_code;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to 
WooCommerce->Settings->Shipping->Shipping Options

and make sure you have unchecked 'Enable the shipping calculator on the cart page'.

Answer (score 0):

All the woocommerce files needs to be overridden by copying that file into your child theme.

Also, In woocommerce backend the option must be checked which tells to Show Shipping Calculator on cart page  (As this will show calculator)

Add below code into woocommerce/cart/cart-shipping.php file before first tr (You will found in file)

```
if(is_checkout() && !$show_shipping_calculator && 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_shipping_calc' )  ) {
        $show_shipping_calculator = true;
}
```

Add below code into your child theme's fuctions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_test' );
        function test_test() {
            if( is_checkout() ) {
                if( wp_script_is( 'wc-cart', 'registered' ) && !wp_script_is( 'wc-cart', 'enqueued' ) ) {
                wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-cart' );
            }
        }
    }
```

Now we need to add id tag in shipping calculator's update totals button, 
For that in woocommerce/cart/shipping-calculator.php page find button which has  name="calc_shipping" and add id tag in that button ====>  id="calc_shipping"

**Note ==>** This is done by us to bind the button click event in jQuery,  You can use your any other alternative way ( If you want )

Now last step,

Add below jquery code in your child theme's js file

```
 jQuery(document).on('click','#calc_shipping',function(e){

                    e.preventDefault();

                    var shipping_country_val    =    jQuery("#calc_shipping_country").val();
                    var shipping_state_val      =    jQuery("#calc_shipping_state").val();
                    var shipping_city_name      =    jQuery("#calc_shipping_city").val();
                    var shipping_postcode       =    jQuery("#calc_shipping_postcode").val();

                    jQuery("#billing_country").val(shipping_country_val);
                    jQuery("#billing_state").val(shipping_state_val);
                    jQuery('#billing_city').val(shipping_city_name);
                    jQuery('#billing_postcode').val(shipping_postcode);
                    jQuery("#shipping_country").val(shipping_country_val);
                    jQuery("#shipping_state").val(shipping_state_val);
                    jQuery('#shipping_city').val(shipping_city_name);
                    jQuery('#shipping_postcode').val(shipping_postcode);

                    $('#billing_country , #shipping_country').trigger('change');
                    $('#billing_state, #shipping_state').trigger('change');
            });
```