# WooCommerce - Show Shipping on Checkout Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I would like to offer in the WooCommerce order process the possibility to offer the customer a service at his home. Now I have created a shipping method with the postal codes where this is offered, but I need the possibility to select the shipping method in the checkout (ideally after entering the address).

I have seen many screenshots where this was possible in the checkout (see picture), and found some instructions how to realize the shipping costs in the checkout (for example: https://websitedepot.com/moving-shipping-rates-woocommerce-checkout/). However, nothing worked.

Maybe someone can help me to implement this.
Thanks a lot!

[image: Source: https://ehost.net/divi-news/how-to-configure-your-woocommerce-shipping-options/]

Answer (score 0):

All woocommerce files need to be overridden by copying that file into your child theme.

Also, In woocommerce backend, the option must be checked which tells to Show Shipping Calculator on the cart page (As this will show calculator)

Add below code into woocommerce/cart/cart-shipping.php file before the first tr (You will found in file)

```
if(is_checkout() && !$show_shipping_calculator && 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_shipping_calc' )  ) {
        $show_shipping_calculator = true;
}
```

Add below code into your child theme's fuctions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_test' );
        function test_test() {
            if( is_checkout() ) {
                if( wp_script_is( 'wc-cart', 'registered' ) && !wp_script_is( 'wc-cart', 'enqueued' ) ) {
                wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-cart' );
            }
        }
    }
```

Now we need to add id tag in shipping calculator's update totals button, For that in woocommerce/cart/shipping-calculator.php page find the button which has name="calc_shipping" and add id tag in that button ====> id="calc_shipping"

Note ==> This is done by us to bind the button click event in jQuery, You can use your any other alternative way ( If you want )

Now the last step,

Add below jquery code in your child theme's js file

```
 jQuery(document).on('click','#calc_shipping',function(e){

                    e.preventDefault();

                    var shipping_country_val    =    jQuery("#calc_shipping_country").val();
                    var shipping_state_val      =    jQuery("#calc_shipping_state").val();
                    var shipping_city_name      =    jQuery("#calc_shipping_city").val();
                    var shipping_postcode       =    jQuery("#calc_shipping_postcode").val();

                    jQuery("#billing_country").val(shipping_country_val);
                    jQuery("#billing_state").val(shipping_state_val);
                    jQuery('#billing_city').val(shipping_city_name);
                    jQuery('#billing_postcode').val(shipping_postcode);
                    jQuery("#shipping_country").val(shipping_country_val);
                    jQuery("#shipping_state").val(shipping_state_val);
                    jQuery('#shipping_city').val(shipping_city_name);
                    jQuery('#shipping_postcode').val(shipping_postcode);

                    $('#billing_country , #shipping_country').trigger('change');
                    $('#billing_state, #shipping_state').trigger('change');
            });
```

Comment: Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327231/shipping-calculator-button-at-checkout-page | I‘ve try this already, but it dont work.

Comment: Please check jquery conflict and function is  added correctly as per the latest theme or php version

Comment: anything is added correctly, but the only thing is see is this code in cart and checkout:
`if(is_checkout() && !$show_shipping_calculator && 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_shipping_calc' )  ) {
        $show_shipping_calculator = true;
}`
I just see the code, but it seems to has no function - i dont know why...

Comment: Then must be a check on a live environment.